# Is it possible to navigate to particular URL on window.unload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to navigate to particular URL on window.unload?

Something like below.......target browser is chrome and safari.

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
            window.location.href = "default.aspx";            
        });
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/icalop/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `<head>` tag.

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
return false;
}
</script>
```

Or if you have an external js, that'd do too.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(. its just asking the confirmation box and navigating to previous page on confirm click.

Comment: well in that case, you might want to send an ajax request to your server and initiate a redirect from there. If it's strictly a javascript redirect that you need, the browser will make sure that the user is Ok with the redirect.